# Dynamic Memory Allocation Hardfault Problem

Tags: c, pointers, lwip

I am using stm32f4 microproccessor and lwip library for the some ethernet process.

I have a problem with dynamic memory allocation. For some reason when I send ping to my hardware, this device experience Hardfault problem after 1 hour.

These are my firmware routine in `main.c`

```
while(1)
{
    uint8_t * incomingData = ethernetif_input(&gnetif);
    
    if(incomingData != NULL)
    {
        if(incomingData[0] == 0x01)
        {
            // doing some process
        }
        incomingData = NULL;
        free(incomingData)
    }
}
```

in `ethernetif.c` :

```
uint8_t * ethernetif_input(struct netif *netif)
{
    struct pbuf *p;
    p = low_level_input(netif);
        if (p == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    uint8_t * data = (uint8_t*)(malloc(sizeof( uint8_t) * 61U));
    if ((memcmp (p->payload, EXPECTED_ETHERNET_FRAME, 6) == 0))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 61; i++) 
        {
            data[i]=(((uint8_t*)p->payload)[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        err = netif->input(p, netif);
        data = NULL;
        free(data);
        if (err != ERR_OK)
        {
            pbuf_free(p);
            p = NULL;
        }
        {
        if(p != NULL)
        {
            pbufFreeErr = pbuf_free(p);
            if( !(_Bool)pbufFreeErr)
            {
        
            } 
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: `incommingData = NULL; free(incommingData);` Mind the *order* of those two.

Comment: Is that a wrong using? When I source on the web. People using this way. How can I use them ?

Comment: What that's doing is `incommingData = NULL; free(NULL);`. What you probably meant it to do is `free(incommingData); incommingData = NULL;`.

Comment: @dxiv So is this the only problem with my code? Is it because of hardfault experience?

Comment: That was the first, obvious problem. Can't say whether it's the only one, since you did not provide complete code or explained who owns what (just as another example, `pbuf *p` looks to be `pbuf_free`'d in some cases, but not all cases).

Comment: Concerning `free(incommingData); incommingData = NULL;`: Everytimes, this is executed (you first override a pointer to (hopefully) some allocated stuff and then try to `free()` the `NULL` pointer), you may produce a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). This will consume all available heap memory sooner or later. I don't know what exactly a _hardfault_ is but you will end up with no more heap available, which usually stalls the system. (On my PC, I noticed that even the mouse pointer doesn't move anymore in such cases.)

Answer (score 2):

You're running out of memory.

As already mentioned in the comments: `data=NULL; free(data)` does not make sense. It says forget what data pointed to and then do nothing with it.
You should first `free(data)`before setting it to NULL. That will make the memory pointed to by `data` available to future `malloc`calls.

And you should also call `pbuf_free` in all cases, you will run out of memory if you don't.

As a final remark, do not use a for loop to copy the buffer, use `memcpy`.

Comment: thank you for your advise, I didnt use memcpy but I am using memcmp